# How can i change the startup page at WP 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I working on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project, I have a page that i want it to be my start up page not the "MainPage.xaml" but when i go to App.Xaml.cs i can't find the responsible code that allow me to change the startup page, so can some one help me in this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it from manifest file. In the solution explorer > Properties >  WMAppManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for this, i really hate the way MS work with every time they change every thing also the simplest things, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Go to App.cs

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
/*...*/
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
      /*...*/

        // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
        // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
        // parameter
        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        }
    }
 /*...*/
```

}

Change the name "MainPage" to the name of your own Page